# Container logs not working after cluster update on GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl

Recently I did an upgrade on my cluster that's running multiple containers for microservices written in Java (using default Spring Boot's log4j2 default configuration). Since then, the container log is not being updated anymore.
The *kubectl logs* command is working fine, all the recent logs can be seen using this command, but the logs that should be appearing in the GKE dashboard is simply not working anymore. I checked the Google's Loggin API and it's enabled.

Does anyone know what's the possible reasons for this or how to solve it?

Comment: Did you enabled a security feature on your cluster? (Like Workload Identity). 
What was the version you had and what is the new one?

Comment: I did not enable any new features on my cluster. The version was 1.12.<something>  and currently it is on 1.15.8-gke.3.

Comment: which version of stackdriver logging are you using? Which stackdriver filter are you using to view the logs?

Comment: Just found that disabling both "Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring/Logging" and enabling the "Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring" can solve this problem. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to disable the **Legacy Stackdriver** and enable **Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring**:

1. Go to the cluster page and click on edit;
2. Disable both Legacy Stackdriver Monitoring and Logging;
3. Enable Stackdriver Kubernetes Engine Monitoring using the option "System and workload logging and monitoring"

Comment: For me this was labelled as "Kubernetes Engine Monitoring".  No mention of stackdriver.